# Copy an image to new location - PHP

Tags: php, image, file-upload, copy, rename

I want to copy and image from the temporary location to the user's background folder, but when I try it it always headers me to the error page.

**Code:**
Here I set the `$fileTmpLoc` and the `$fileName` variable

```
$imgtype = $_POST['imgtype'];
    $fileTmpLoc = "";
    $fileName = "";
    if($imgtype == "universe"){
        $fileTmpLoc = "../images/universebi.jpg";
        $fileName = "universebi.jpg";
    }else if($imgtype == "flowers"){
        $fileTmpLoc = "../images/flowersbi.jpg";
        $fileName = "flowersbi.jpg";
    }else if($imgtype == "forest"){
        $fileTmpLoc = "../images/forestbi.jpg";
        $fileName = "forestbi.jpg";
    }else if($imgtype == "bubbles"){
        $fileTmpLoc = "../images/bubblesbi.jpg";
        $fileName = "bubblesbi.jpg";
    }else if($imgtype == "mountains"){
        $fileTmpLoc = "../images/mountainsbi.jpg";
        $fileName = "mountainsbi.jpg";
    }else if($imgtype == "waves"){
        $fileTmpLoc = "../images/wavesbi.jpg";
        $fileName = "wavesbi.jpg";
    }else if($imgtype == "stones"){
        $fileTmpLoc = "../images/stonesbi.jpg";
        $fileName = "stonesbi.jpg";
    }else if($imgtype == "simple"){
        $fileTmpLoc = "../images/simplebi.png";
        $fileName = "simplebi.png";
    }
```

Here I set the `$fileExt` variable and create the `background` folder if it's not already created.

```
$kaboom = explode(".", $fileName);
    $fileExt = end($kaboom);

    $db_file_name = "bibg".rand(3333,7777).".".$fileExt;
    if (!file_exists("../user/$log_username/background")) {
        mkdir("../user/$log_username/background", 0755);
    }
```

And here is the wrong code. I want to copy the image from the `$fileTmpLoc` to the `$newFileLoc`, but it fails. However, if I try it with the `rename` function it works fine, but I don't want to remove the image, because these images are in my computer. So, I want to copy them somehow and move to copy to the proper folder.

```
$newFileLoc = "../user/$log_username/background/$db_file_name";
    if(!copy($fileTmpLoc, $newFileLoc)){
        header('location: ../file_upload_error.php');
        exit();
    }
```

At the end I just insret the variables into the database

```
$sql = "UPDATE useroptions SET background='$db_file_name' WHERE username='$log_username' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_close($conn);
    echo "bibg_success";
    exit();
```

So is there any solution?

Comment: No, there are the built-in backgrounds on the website, you can also upload your own image.

Comment: are you sure that your directory has the right permission?

Comment: Yes, as I said this code worked good when I used the `rename` function instead of `copy`.